# 360 VIDEO BACKGROUND site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Looking to create a site with 360 videos using a Vimeo or youtube player. Because the video is in the background it doesn't allow me to click and drag to use the 360 effects. Even when I don't place it in the background, that control doesn't seem to be working when the site is on fullscreen. Need to be able to overlay the video with some text and buttons.

```css
 body{
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        font-family: 'Helvetica';
     font-size:16px;
    }

.contact{
    color:white;
}

.logo{
    font-family:'times';
    font-size:22px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo a{text-decoration: none;
color:black;
font-size:80px;}

 
html {
    font: 0.75em/1.5 sans-serif;
    background: #000;

}

.vimeo-wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index:0 ;
   pointer-events: none;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.vimeo-wrapper iframe {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 56.25vw; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 9/16*100 = 56.25 */
   min-height: 100vh;
   min-width: 177.77vh; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 16/9*100 = 177.77 */
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.instruct{
  position: fixed;
    bottom:4vh;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.menu{
     position: fixed;
    right:4vh;
 font-weight:400;
    font-family:'times';
    font-size:20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right; 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
   
button{
        padding:20px;
        background-color:black;
        opacity: .65;
        color:white;
        margin: 10px;
                font-family: 'Helvetica';
        font-weight: bold;
        border:0px; 
    }
 
button:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color:#000;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
  position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    }


h1{
  font-family:'Helvetica';
  font-size:30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color:#000;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
    
<!-- The video -->
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
 <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/209094416?&background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&byline=0&title=0&mute=1&controls=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<!-- VIDEO ENDS-->
    
    
<!-- SITE OVERLAY -->
<div class="content">
    <div class="menu">
    home</div>
    
    
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">caroline </a></div>
    
    <a href=""><button>hey buddy</button></a>
    <a href=""><button>Bye Buddy</button></a>
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="instruct">Click & Drag to look around</div>


</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: Check this: https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2018/08/control-your-360-videos-with-youtube.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you this did work but i can't figure out out to hide the titles, autoplay, mute, hide controls etc. how can i add that into the js?